# Time between ccTouchMoved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to know how much time has elapsed between calls to the ccTouchMoved method in Cocos2D or some type of global variable that I could use to keep track of how much time has elapsed since the method was last called. Any ideas would be very much apreciated =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() returns the value of the current time down to some tiny fraction of a second. You could save that to a double iVar and compare the saved value to the current one.

Comment: Thanks, this actually did help with the Issue I was having, I really apreciate it =)

Comment: Nice I had only known of CACurrentMediaTime().

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSDate field that you can access from your ccTouchBegan & ccTouchMoved methods:

```
NSDate* _touchStart;
```

In ccTouchBegan:

```
_touchStart = [NSDate date];
```

In ccTouchMoved:

```
NSTimeInterval elapsed = [_touchStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

I haven't tested this; it's off the top of my head. NSTimeInterval is actually a double that measures in seconds, with accuracy at least to 1 millisecond:

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

Hope this helps!